# How can I create a Signaling server in Python for peer to peer video calling using WebRTC + SIP.js

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, webrtc, sip

I got a college project, which is based on peer to peer video calling. I have to use webrtc for client side and python for server side. For signaling, I have to use sip.js. I know a little bit about webrtc and python. I know how to create node.js server using socket.io but don't know about python websocket server. Someone please give me any code or link for p2p video calling using python+sip.js+webrtc.
How can I understand and resolve this problem?